# PostgreSQL in Rails query is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, datetime, activerecord

New to PostgreSQL (and only 6 months more experienced in programming in general), having problems with following query:

```
TutoringSession.where("extract (DOW from begin_time)
                     = extract DOW from (?)", Time.now)
```

Gives me the following error message:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DOW"
LINE 1: ..."  WHERE (extract (DOW from begin_time) = extract DOW from (...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "tutoring_sessions".* FROM "tutoring_sessions"  WHERE (extract (DOW from   begin_time) = extract DOW from ('2012-04-18 14:39:58.202249'))
```

I have looked through the PostgreSQL documentation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Updated after comment.</sup>
You misplaced a parenthesis. And add an explicit type cast.

```
TutoringSession.where("extract (DOW from begin_time)
                     = extract (DOW from timestamp ?)", Time.now)
```

If you just want to insert the current time, you can let PostgreSQL do that for you - provided the time on the database server works for you. [Consider time zones.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT)

```
TutoringSession.where("extract (DOW from begin_time)
                     = extract (DOW from now())")
```

[The manual about `extract()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT).

Comment: TutoringSession.where("extract (DOW from begin_time) = extract (DOW from ?)", Time.now)
  TutoringSession Load (2.2ms)  SELECT "tutoring_sessions".* FROM "tutoring_sessions" WHERE (extract (DOW from begin_time) = extract (DOW from '2012-04-18 15:11:55.832108'))                         
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  function pg_catalog.date_part(unknown, unknown) is not unique
LINE 1: ...sessions"  WHERE (extract (DOW from begin_time) = extract (D...                               HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.